# Can't drawImage() on Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, clojurescript

I cannot seem to render a [subsection of a PNG to an HTML canvas](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#images). I have a canvas 2D context and an image preloaded, `onload` I try to draw the image on the canvas but nothing happens. No errors in my browser console either.

```
(ns jump.core)

(enable-console-print!)

(defn screen
  ([]
     (screen "screen"))
  ([elem-id]
     (let [screen (.getElementById js/document elem-id)]
       {:context (.getContext screen "2d")
        :height (.-height screen)
        :width (.-width screen)})))

(defn draw-sprite
  [player screen]
  (let [ctx (:context screen)
        sprite (:image player)
        t (:top player)
        l (:left player)
        w (:width player)
        h (:height player)]
    (println ctx sprite l t w h 10 10 w h)
    (.drawImage ctx sprite l t w h 10 10 w h)))

(defn image
  [src]
  (let [img (new js/Image)]
    (set! (.-src img) src)
    img))

(def player
  {:image (image "sprites/player.png")
   :top 94
   :left 167
   :height 35
   :width 37
   :facing :right
   :falling false
   :jumping false})

(set! (.-onload js/window)
      (do
        (println "Window loaded")
        (println "player" player)
        (println "screen" (screen))
        (draw-sprite player (screen))))
```

The full code is available in [my github repo](https://github.com/gknapp/jump/blob/develop/src/cljs/jump/core.cljs).

[image: browser console output]

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wait till `onload` fires in the image, it may be empty when you are painting it because it still hasn't come back from the server.

Quick and ugly solution:

```
(defn init []
  (println "Window loaded")
  (println "player" player)
  (println "screen" (screen))
  (draw-sprite player (screen)))

(set! (.-onload js/window)
      #(set! (.-onload (:image player))
             init))
```

If this was the problem you are probably going to need some code to manage loading resources!

--

Also, I've noticed that you are assigning to the window.onload the result of the `do` expression. You probably wanted to assign an anonymous function:

```
(set! (.-onload js/window)
      #(do
        (println "Window loaded")
        (println "player" player)
        (println "screen" (screen))
        (draw-sprite player (screen))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I took this apart today and wrote out the JS version to get it working, before scratching my head with the CLJS some more. I did end up using `img.onload = func() {};` in the JS version. I'll try out your suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: I've not forgotten about this, just not got round to implementing it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For future people that find this question, here's my solution. I chose to use `Base64` image encoding so that the image is loaded right when the canvas tries to draw the image.

1. First I fetch the canvas where the image will be drawn:

   ```
   (defn canvas
     "gets a canvas with a certain id"
     [id]
     (.getElementById js/document id))
   ```
2. Then I retrieve the context of that canvas.

   ```
   (defn context-2d
     "gets the 2d context of a canvas with an id"
     [id]
     (let [canvas-elem (canvas id)]
       (.getContext canvas-elem "2d")))
   ```
3. Next, I get the appropriate image. `data` corresponds to the `Base64` image encoded string.

   ```
   ((defn get-img
     "retrieves an image with data"
     [data]
     (let [img (js/Image.)]
       (set! (.-src img) data)
       img))
   ```
4. Lastly, I draw the image, from the previous step, onto the context.

   ```
   (defn draw-image
     "draws the image"
     [ctx img x y width height]
     (.drawImage ctx img x y width height))
   ```